# How to define boundaries of a reporting microservice?

Tags: javascript, node.js, architecture, microservices

Assuming I have an `Order Service` that provides an API for creating, updating, and canceling orders. The user must be able, when necessary, to generate a PDF with the order details.

I don't particularly like `Order Service` to contain the necessary logic (and all dependencies) to do this PDF generation, because if I need to implement PDF generation in more parts of the system, I would have to load tons of dependencies on each microservice, besides that it seems that the microservice has more responsibilities than it should.

But on the other hand, if I create a `Reporting Service` to generate these PDFs, I would be taking into account technical concerns, moreover, each service would have to send the data, the template and the settings for the `Reporting Service` and receive the generated PDF file back over the network, which can be a bottleneck.

Taking into account which Chris Richardson says in Microservices Patterns book:

> microservices should be organized around business concerns rather than
> technical concerns

How could this be designed without be a violation of bounded context and maintaining the separation of concerns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to write the logic to generate PDF in a library and use the library in the needed Microservice.

Developing a separate microservice for PDF generation is not a good option reason PDF generation depends on (1.) Data from another microservice and (2.) Template to convert the Data in PDF. So, lots of data flow will be there.

Comment: It also doesn't seem like a good option. New version of this kind of shared libs will affect all services and complicate the deployments. The consequence is at some point nobody trust himselve do develop next releases of common shared library, as it can affect many services.

Comment: I agree, that shared library add complexity in term of deployment or DevOps. It is not always a good option for Microservice architecture style. But in some case, we can go with this option. I feel that you may try library option in specific to PDF case.

Answer (score 0):

PDF rendering is no different from any other view-layer concern.  Encapsulate it at the same sort of granularity/separation as you would use to render the order to the web page.

As you would likely not handle HTML/JS rendering of the order in the order service, you likely wouldn't want to handle rendering of the order there either.  Keep your PDF rendering in a dedicated service that knows how to render them, and pass the required data to it.  Although the order service likely doesn't call this service, it will likely call the order service.

Comment: just to see if I got it right, your idea would then be treat the PDF service as a view-layer, being tightly coupled to the ordering service, where would it call the ordering service to get the data to generate the PDF?

Comment: Yup, it's not different from any other rendering.